# How do I boot a Raspberry Pi directly into browser?

Tags: linux, bashrc, raspberry-pi

I have put the following line in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file:

```
chromium--kiosk www.bbc.co.uk
```

However I then get an error at start up:

```
(chromium:2100): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

If I set the Pi to boot into OS at startup, chromium never appears, but if I start a terminal window it suddenly opens chromium in kiosk mode and with the specified web page!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put that in you xinitrc.

Comment: Which DE? If you're using Arch + Openbox, you could add it to the `~/.config/openbox/autostart`, otherwise as @TomWijsman suggested, the `~/.xinitrc` should work.  I might put a `(sleep 3 && command) &` in there to wait for X to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

anything in the /etc/bash.bashrc is run when a shell starts up (which doesnt have an xdisplay)  - see [What is the .bashrc file?](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-bashrc-file) for more info. Try adding that line into the file that your desktop enviroment uses when it logs in the user.

If you are using lxde, which I assume,

http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart

and edit it to your specifiacitons:
so it should look like:

```
[Desktop Entry] 


Type=Application


Exec=chromium--kiosk www.bbc.co.uk
```

Comment: Thanks agovizer. Just to confirm what I did to get this to work. I added "@chromium --kiosk www.bbc.co.uk" to the autostart file in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/. It now boots into the desktop and then starts chromium in kiosk mode. It would be nice to never see the desktop, but that is just a minor gripe. Other than that it works as I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "screenly" it actually can run in kiosk mode (using UZBL) and can even be interactive with a keyboard and mouse. (ability to lock to certain sites and block actions available as well). You could accomplish this easily though by simply scheduling a web asset to that URL. Screenly boots instantly never showing the desktop.