# KDE bash --norc

Tags: kde, bashrc

I would like to disable ./bashrc with the command bash --norc when opening a session on the KDE Destop enviroment.
but I dont really understand where to place it, if on the startkde, Xsession or where else

Answer (score 0):

If the restriction is to be set upon an interactive yet non-login shell (launched from Konsole) then you can follow these steps:

1. Launch Konsole
2. Go to **Settings → Edit Current Profile** → edit **Command** field into `/bin/bash --norc` → **Apply → OK**.
3. Close the Konsole or either launch a new tab and you'll see `.bashrc` isn't loaded.

If you want to set this restriction on a login shell then I suggest changing the name of `.bashrc` to something else (say `._bashrc`).
Because `.bashrc` is supposed to be reloaded on every new instance of bash, you'll see the effects immediately on both interactive and login/non-login shell.

Tested on Slackware 14.1 running KDE 4.10.

Read more:

- [What is the difference between interactive shells, login shells, non-login shell and their use cases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/what-is-the-difference-between-interactive-shells-login-shells-non-login-shell)
- [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work)
- [What is the .bashrc file?](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file)