# What's the equivalent of .bashrc for CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, csh

By configuring `~/.bashrc` as desired, each time the user logs into their bash shell the configured settings (of `.bashrc`) will automatically be set. Now I must be missing something but despite thorough [DuckDuckGo](https://DuckDuckGo.com)'ing I cannot figure out the equivalent for **C-shell**.

As a reference for bash-shell, there is a thorough explanation of configuring its default settings at the question:  [What is the .bashrc file?](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file)

For reference, I am using CentOS: 
(As you may have guessed, LINUX isn't my forte)

```
[user@computer ~]$ uname -r
2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
[user@computer ~]$ lsb_release -a                                                                           
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Release:        6.6
Codename:       Final
```

Many thanks for reading this.

-- Edit --
Fixed tags.

-- Edit 2 --
Meant to include that this is also a very good (related) question: 
[What is the .bashrc file?](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csh` is really `tcsh` on almost all systems, including CentOS. From the tcsh manpage (`tcsh(1)`):

> **Startup and shutdown**
>
> A login shell begins  by  executing  commands  from  the  system  files
>   `/etc/csh.cshrc`  and  `/etc/csh.login`.   It  then  executes commands from
>   files in  the  user's  home  directory:  first  `~/.tcshrc`  (+)  or,  if
>   `~/.tcshrc`  is not found, `~/.cshrc`, then `~/.history` (or the value of the
>   `histfile shell` variable), then `~/.login`, and finally `~/.cshdirs` (or the
>   value  of  the  dirsfile  shell  variable)  (+).   The  shell  may read
>   `/etc/csh.login` before instead of  after  `/etc/csh.cshrc`,  and  `~/.login`
>   before  instead  of  after  `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc` and `~/.history`, if so
>   compiled; see the version shell variable. (+)
>
> Non-login shells read only `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc`  on
>   startup.
>
> [... rest of the section trimmed ...]

I personally like to just use `~/.tcshrc`. If you want, you can "detect" a login shell like so:

```
setenv PATH /bin:/sbin/:...

if ( $?prompt ) then
    exit
endif

# This is only for interactive shells
set color
set printexitvalue
```

Comment: Thank you very much, creating and modifying `~/.tcshrc` does the job.

Comment: A side note regarding the manpage: On my system `~/.history` contains the history of the commands  that I've entered previously. So I doubt that modifying it would have the desired effect here.