# Make a RAM Disk on Linux that does not change file system after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, vmware-workstation, ramdisk

I create a RAM Disk on Ubuntu 16.10 (running within a VM) with the following commands

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/RAMDisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/RAMDisk
```

After this, if I go into the RAMDisk and do this

```
df .
```

I get the following

```
tmpfs            2097152     0   2097152   0% /media/RAMDisk
```

So far so good.

Then I reboot Ubuntu (which reboots the VM running via Workstation Pro).

After reboot, I expect either the `/media/RAMDisk` folder to not exist at all, or to exist as a **`tmpfs`** file system with no contents in it.

The `/media/RAMDisk` folder does exist with no contents, but surprisingly as a `/dev/sda1` file system. When I do `df .` with `/media/RAMDisk`, I see this:

```
    /dev/sda1       17413904 9577448   6928836  59% /
```

Now, I could easily put the commands within my `.bashrc` and have them run and do the right things everytime, but I need to know what is going on.

Also, could my virtual machine manager -- Workstation Pro -- be doing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is going on?

Nothing unusual.

`df /media/RAMDisk`, when it refers to `/dev/sda1`, tells you the directory at the moment belongs to the filesystem on `/dev/sda1` which is mounted on `/`.

This is because the effect of your `mount` command is not permanent, it doesn't survive reboot. On the other hand the `mkdir` command created a directory inside the filesystem of `/dev/sda1` and this filesystem is mounted after every reboot so the directory itself survives, but as a part of `/dev/sda1` filesystem.

You need to mount `RAMDisk` after (or at) every boot somehow.

---

#### How to mount?

Running `mount` from within `.bashrc` is not a good idea because [this file may be sourced multiple times](https://superuser.com/a/49292/432690) during a single session. Since you need `sudo` anyway, it will be better to use `/etc/rc.local` which is run once when OS starts.

But the even better way may be to add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /media/RAMDisk tmpfs defaults,nosuid,nodev,size=2048M 0 0
```

Investigate `user` and `noauto` options (see `man 5 fstab`) and maybe you would like to use them and invoke `mount /media/RAMDisk` on demand only.

---

#### `systemd`?

[This site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) makes me believe you can run a `systemd` unit when a given user logs in for the first time and terminate it as soon as the last session for the user is closed. I'm not very familiar with `systemd`, so I can't tell you how (if) you can do it with `.mount` unit.

But if you use `systemd` then you should already have a personal `tmpfs` mounted on `/run/user/<UID>`. The system-wide one should be on `/dev/shm`.

---

#### About `/media/`

Also note `/media/` is used by Ubuntu to create mountpoints e.g. for external USB drives (I believe `udisks2` is responsible). They may look like `/media/<username>/<label>` so I guess `/media/RAMDisk` is not going to collide with anything. In general I would avoid using this location though. In my systems (Debian, Kubuntu, Raspbian, OpenWRT) I use `/mnt/<something>` and I have never had any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful answer. I will try the options you suggested.